# UseQuery Async Variables Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, graphql

I am trying to make a simple useQuery request but the variables which I am dependent on for the request are being loaded asynchronously. My apologies in advance for the kind of messy variable names.

Currently I have a useQuery hook which I want to function like this.

```
 const { id } = router.query;

 let userDbAddress;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUsernameEthAddress() {
      userDbAddress = await getUserAddressFromUsernameDb(id);
    }
    getUsernameEthAddress();
    return () => (mountedRef.current = false);
  }, [router.isReady]);

  let userVariables = {
    where: {
      id: userDbAddress,
    },
  };

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USER_DATA, {
    variables: userVariables,   //<<<I AM NULL (because running before async useEffect completes!)
  });
  if (loading) return null;
  if (error) return <Error statusCode={404} />;

  const myData = data?.myData;
```

My problem is that the asynchronous is in the ordering of my data. The userDbAddress is null when the useQuery is called and I am not sure when I can best pass it into the variables parameter for my query. I am not sure if this is the proper use case for useLazyQuery?
I want my query to run on page render just after the useEffect hook runs so that I can wire up the userDbAddress variable to pass into the useQuery hook.

Thanks for taking the time:)

And happy to clarify if the question is too messy/wordy

Comment: you do nothing with `userDbAddress` so there's no point of `getUsernameEthAddress` being `async` since the awaited value (`userDbAddress`) is irrelevant

Comment: You need to `useState` for `userDbAddress`.

Comment: `useLazyQuery` (or other ways to skip the query unless `userDbAddress` has a value) would be an appropriate solution, yes. The possibly easier thing though would be to just call `fetch` directly from the `getUsernameEthAddress` effect

Answer (score 0):

This is `react-query` right?

If so, there is a 3rd parameter to set options for the query. Just add `{ enabled: false }` as an option in that 3rd parameter and the query won't fire off immediately. Secondly, pull the `refetch` function from the object returned from `useQuery()`. Then, once `userVariables` has valid data (you can create a `useEffect()` for this), you can call `refetch()` and your expected flow work work now.